# aspnetzero unAuthorizedRequest for 1st logon

Tags: aspnetboilerplate

I am getting the below error message for a 1st time into my aspnetzero db. I have tried many of the solutions suggested in other areas but none seem to work for my local db

The db owner is sa and i have made the default password set to the infamous '123qwe'; i checked user mapping to make sure that sa owns the db.

i get the below error message when i try to login to the zero system; so the migration works OK also.

{"result":null,"targetUrl":"/Account/ResetPassword?UserId=1&ResetCode=56FB4BDF82&ReturnUrl=%2FApp",
"success":true,"error":null,"unAuthorizedRequest":false,"__abp":true}

Answer (score 1):

well for this issue; the problem was that I wanted 2 pc's, a PC for the road and a desktop for travel, to have a single solution; using GitHub.

in setting up the 2nd pc, I did not follow the exact instructions for creating the project.

Thought I downloaded GitHub repository, something did not work ok in doing the yarn, etc.

To finally fix the problem I re-deleted the solution on the local PC, downloaded the GitHub repository, made sure I did the yarn, vs2k17 build (do not run it) c) npm run create-bundles or npm run full-create.

the below is what helped: 
https://support.aspnetzero.com/QA/Questions/6176
I just ran into the same error message.
My issue was caused by Visual Studio running the package restore via npm.
Deleting the node_modules folder and running the restore via yarn in the command line resolved the problem and allowed me to run the copy:node_modules gulp task without errors.